# Does FusedLocationProviderClient need to initialize? location often null

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get GPS location but I've noticed that it is often `null`, especially on the first couple of location pulls. Does it need to initialize for it to pull the location on the first try? Here is the code I'm using which works sometimes but never the first time it seems.

```
val locationManager: LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
if((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        val location: Location? = task.result
            if(location != null) {
                latitude = location.latitude.toString()
                longitude = location.longitude.toString()
            } else {
                val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
                locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                locationRequest.interval = 0
                locationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
                locationRequest.numUpdates = 1
                fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallBack, Looper.myLooper())
            }
        }
    }
}

private val locationCallBack = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
        val location: Location? = p0?.lastLocation

        if(location != null) {
            latitude = location.latitude.toString()
            longitude = location.longitude.toString()
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the tutorial I used now, but was able to get this to work with the following code. Below code is for the future lonely stackoverflow traveler.

```
build.gradle
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
...
```

```
Androidmanifest.xml
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" /> <!-- I think this is required for Android 10 (API 29) + -->
...
```

```
class ClassName : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val locationCallBack: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
            val location: Location? = p0?.lastLocation
            if(location != null) {
                latitude = location.latitude.toString()
                longitude = location.longitude.toString()
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        getLocation()
        ...
    }
    private fun getLocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val locationManager: LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    val location: Location? = task.result
                    if(location == null)
                        requestLocation()
                    else {
                        latitude = location.latitude.toString()
                        longitude = location.longitude.toString()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun requestLocation() {
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 0
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
        locationRequest.numUpdates = 1
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallBack, Looper.myLooper())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last known location is a cached value that gets wiped from time to time (e.g. after phone reboot). If you want a more persistent way to get a GPS location, [request location updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates) and unsubscribe as soon as you get the first result.